# Group data from table in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have a table sql like this

```
post_id    point    user_id
5          1.0      1
6          1.5      1
7          0.0      2
8          1.5      3
9          1.0      3
...
```

I want to print the data into this ( group the posts by user_id )

```
user_id        post_id(point)                     total point
1              5(1.0)  |  6(1.5)    | ...         2.5
2              7(0.0)  |            | ...         0.0
3              8(1.5)  | 9(1.5)     | ...         3.0
...
```

I tried something like this, but it returned array

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE post_id = ?
```

I'm sorry if this a silly question but I'm newbie in MySQL

Comment: And what you have tried so far?

Comment: Can you show your attempt?

Comment: Ok I've added my code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run a query where you `GROUP BY` the `user_id`. Use `GROUP_CONCAT()` with `CONCAT()` to generate your points/posts column. `CONCAT()` puts together the string to form the `postID (points)` format, `GROUP_CONCAT()` puts all the values grouped by that group (in this case the `user_id`) into one string separated by the separator `|`.

```
SELECT user_id, 
       GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(post_id, '(', points, ')')  SEPARATOR ' | ') as point_id_posts,
       SUM(points) as totalPoint
FROM table
GROUP BY user_id
```

- Live demo at https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/aGHL49ydsUX3LnyAfut4vx/0

Answer (score 1):

This is a job for `GROUP BY` and [`GROUP_CONCAT()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat).  Try something like this.

(https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4sVVgGk6SyEnFE4C3emMp9/0)

```
SELECT user_id,
       GROUP_CONCAT( CONCAT(post_id, '(', point, ')') ORDER BY post_id SEPARATOR ' | ' ),
       SUM(point) 
  FROM tbl
 GROUP BY user_id
```

Answer (score 1):

I think This will help you

```
SELECT user_id,GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(post_id,'(',point,')') SEPERATOR ' | ') as post_points,SUM(point) as total_points FROM table_name GROUP BY user_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Query to achieve your requirment

```
SELECT user_id,
       GROUP_CONCAT( CONCAT(post_id, '(', point, ')') ORDER BY post_id SEPARATOR ' | ' ) as post_id_point,
       SUM(point) 
  FROM tbl
 GROUP BY user_id
```